# HTML Scorling default page

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using this JSfidle link to create a sliding page content: http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/rs2QK/

I'm really happy with it, but I want it to show the first target by default, what I have tried  is replacing the panel class of the first target, replacing it with the active class, then it shows up on default, but when I then click for the first time a target, the text of the first target stays untill I click on a target link again.

```
<div id="left">
<a href="#target1" class="panel">Target 1</a><br/>
<a href="#target2" class="panel">Target 2</a><br/>
<a href="#target3" class="panel">Target 3</a><br/>
</div>

<div id="right">
<div class="active" id="target1" style="background:green">Target 1</div>
<div class="panel" id="target2" style="background:red">Target 2</div>
<div class="panel" id="target3" style="background:yellow">Target 3</div>
</div>
```

Does anybody have any tips to fix this?

Thank you,

Bob

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't mind the animation at the page load, the simplest fix would be to trigger the click event on the first panel:

```
$('a.panel').eq(0).click();
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/rs2QK/2826/

---

UPDATE

And to avoid the page load animation, you can simply add the `active` class to the first panel and make it visible via CSS:

```
div.active.panel {
    display: block;
}
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/rs2QK/2828/

Comment: No problem, you could probably make more improvements, but this is good to start with. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution that all you require is triggering a click on first link when page loads

```
var $buttons= $('a.panel').click(function() {
        var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
            $other = $target.siblings('.active');

        if (!$target.hasClass('active')) {
            $other.each(function(index, self) {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.removeClass('active').animate({
                    left: $this.width()
                }, 500);
            });

            $target.addClass('active').show().css({
                left: -($target.width())
            }).animate({
                left: 0
            }, 500);
        }
    });

    $buttons.first().click()
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rs2QK/2825/)**</kbd>

Comment: So if you make a nice demo button, you get an upvote even if you post the same thing two minutes after me? :D One more from me as well.

Comment: Okay, I take my +1 back, thought you could recognize a joke... Sorry I bothered.